# Angular directive remove element binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I've got a directive which has a special handler `foo` for images that cause an `error`.  `foo` updates the source of the bad image with the default image.  It's got a binding as follows:

```
element0.bind('error', foo);
```

The problem is, if the default image source causes an error, `foo` is called infinite-ly.

Is there a way to kill the binding after it's called once?  Among other things, I've tried

- deleting `foo`
- re-binding to null
- deleting the return value from `.bind()`

Any ideas?  I'll probably redesign this but the question remains nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element0.unbind('error', foo);
```

This answer is specific to jQuery, but it is the same for Angular jqLite.

As for jQuery, `bind` and `unbind` are obsolete in favour of `on` and `off`.

The arguments against usage of jQuery in Angular apply to this case. It is preferable to stick to scope events instead:

```
var errorListener = $scope.$on('error', foo);
```

And the listener is removed with

```
errorListener();
```

Comment: Thanks!  To make the binding on a specific element, I have to use `.on()`, but this is a JQuery method, right - what do you recommend in this case?

Comment: Actually, running into problems with the scope event - it's not detecting any errors.  But the `.unbind()` solution works well.

Comment: If there is a separate scope for the element, it is bound to this element also, so it should be fine - if $emit/$broadcase suits the scope hierarchy. Post a question if you ever want to investigate it.